# Override Boolean Filtering in GridView WPF, Apply Custom bool filter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridview, telerik

I know I've asked the exact same question here ([Override default Boolean Filtering in GridView WPF, Apply Custom bool filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822604/override-default-boolean-filtering-in-gridview-wpf-apply-custom-bool-filter)) BUT the result wasn't the one expected.
In fact, the checkbox should be the "default" one from the DatagridView and not the "checkbox" item. They are not the same.

This code provide a checkbox item:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Intégrée" UniqueName="Intégrée" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsIntegree, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" ShowDistinctFilters="True">
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsIntegree, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

This one provide a checkbox from the GridViewDataColumn with "ThreeState". The view result aren't the same.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Intégrée" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsIntegree, Mode=OneWay}" ShowDistinctFilters="True"/>
```

In the code behind I did change the output inside the filter BUT there is no more Binding from the string value ("Vrai") to the booleans values in rows ("True"):

```
private void GridView_DistinctValuesLoading(object sender, GridViewDistinctValuesLoadingEventArgs e)
{
    var col = ((Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView)sender).GetDistinctValues(e.Column, false);
    IEnumerable<string> enu = col.Cast<bool>().Select(t => t.ToString());
    ICollection<string> distinctValues = enu.ToList();
    distinctValues.Clear();
    distinctValues.Add("Vrai");
    distinctValues.Add("Faux");
    e.ItemsSource = distinctValues;
}
```

How can I bind the String value to the boolean value in rows to Filter my rows ?

Comment: What's the difference between the CheckBoxes?

Comment: The item "checkbox" has a "check" in it, I don't want it. The "default" from the dataGridView is completly filled with the software color. I'm posting the picture.

Comment: here is the result I need from datagridView : https://ibb.co/nrTynQ and not the "classic" checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply whatever `Telerik` theme you are using to the `CheckBox`:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Intégrée" UniqueName="Intégrée" DataMemberBinding="{Binding IsIntegree, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" ShowDistinctFilters="True">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsIntegree, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <CheckBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <telerik:Windows8Theme x:Key="Theme" />
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Setter Property="telerik:StyleManager.Theme" Value="{StaticResource Theme}"/>
                    </Style>
                </CheckBox.Style>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know it was Windows8 theme by default. That's why. I thought that it was the DataGridView who managed the "conversion" from boolean to checkbox.